# How to configure easyadminbundle on Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

According to http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-best-practices.html there are no/limited use cases for a `config.yml` file. Where should I put the `easy_admin` configuration for entities it manages with symfony 4?

Comment: I have not tried it myself but the config file would go under config\packages

Comment: yeah, see https://github.com/javiereguiluz/easy-admin-demo/pull/54/files#diff-16eb3931c827c426c299db82e2d8be5b

Answer (score 7):

You have to configure EasyAdminBundle in `config/packages/easy_admin.yaml`

It will be automatically handled by the kernel. You can have a look in `src/Kernel.php`, especially the `configureContainer()` method